# Add admin user to ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails
I am developing application which have four users Patient,Doctor,Nurse and Admin i have created patient user using devise now i want to create Admin user which will be used to do all administrative tasks like display all registered patients, etc..
so how can i add the new user to rails application. Do i need to create a new controllers for them

I tried to create the new user by referring this web page 
http://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/03/creating-user-and-admin-model-using-devise-rails/

but it creates new files and update some existing files when i run this command

$rails generate devise:views

is it there feature or something went wrong i don't have an idea ?
please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one devise user table with have one column as role_name:string which will save the your role name (Patient,Doctor,Nurse, Admin) and for admin it should be 'admin'...
And if its one in app then you will create by seed file (app/db/seed.rb) 
As User.create(email: , password: , roll_name: 'admin' ) then
  rake db:seed